# Exception locking surface, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, multithreading, locking

I am using a thread to handle a wallpaper and using surface view. I am getting the following error and unable to solve it. There is an answer in which they told that there is problem in the sequence of lock `surfaceHolder.lockcanvas()` and `surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)`. But i check and it is right.
plese help someone..
 the LogCat is below:

```
07-06 12:58:24.459: E/SurfaceTextureClient(719): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
07-06 12:58:24.459: E/SurfaceTextureClient(719): queueBuffer (handle=0x2a185508) failed (No such device)
07-06 12:58:24.470: W/System.err(719): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
07-06 12:58:24.479: W/System.err(719):  at android.view.Surface.nativeUnlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
07-06 12:58:24.489: W/System.err(719):  at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:457)
07-06 12:58:24.489: W/System.err(719):  at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:215)
07-06 12:58:24.489: W/System.err(719):  at com.shagun.sunsetlivewallpaper.BackgroundSelector$LeafThread.run(BackgroundSelector.java:160)
07-06 12:58:24.630: E/SurfaceTextureClient(719): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
07-06 12:58:24.649: E/InputEventReceiver(719): channel '40ee2318 com.shagun.sunsetlivewallpaper.WallpaperService (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719): Exception locking surface
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719):   at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719):   at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:447)
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719):   at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.internalLockCanvas(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:184)
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719):   at com.android.internal.view.BaseSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(BaseSurfaceHolder.java:157)
07-06 12:58:24.690: E/BaseSurfaceHolder(719):   at com.shagun.sunsetlivewallpaper.BackgroundSelector$LeafThread.run(BackgroundSelector.java:145)
07-06 12:58:24.690: W/dalvikvm(719): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
07-06 12:58:24.719: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-68
07-06 12:58:24.719: E/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 12:58:24.719: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.shagun.sunsetlivewallpaper.BackgroundSelector.drawScreen(BackgroundSelector.java:85)
07-06 12:58:24.719: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.shagun.sunsetlivewallpaper.BackgroundSelector.access$1(BackgroundSelector.java:80)
07-06 12:58:24.719: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.shagun.sunsetlivewallpaper.BackgroundSelector$LeafThread.run(BackgroundSelector.java:148)
07-06 12:58:30.680: I/Process(719): Sending signal. PID: 719 SIG: 9
```

Comment: How you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.sleep(200);
```

That's helped me when it crushed.
You can see more:

[End SurfaceView and GameThread on exiting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994404/end-surfaceview-and-gamethread-on-exiting-app/21996098#21996098)

Comment: 6 years after your comment I started to receive crashes on Android 13 only.
"sleep" helped me as well. Thanks a lot)

Answer (score -2):

```
  try{
                 if(canvas != null)
                 {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                 }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
```