# End SurfaceView and GameThread on exiting app

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, exit

I've got a surfaceview and a gameThread class.
The gameThread keeps updating and painting on the SurfaceView class.

Now when I exit the app (By pressing the home or back button) I get a message that the app force closed. That's because the GameThread still tries to draw on the erased surfaceview...

So how do i properly end the app without getting this force close notification? I would like the GameThread class to stop when the back button is pressed. It should pause when pressing on home and running in the background. When re-entering the still running game it should resume....

Any ideas?

This is my GameThread class:

```
public class GameThread extends Thread{

private GameView view;
public boolean isRunning = false;

public GameThread(GameView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public void setRunning(boolean setRunning) {
    isRunning = setRunning;
}

public void run() {
    while(isRunning) {
        Canvas c = null;
        view.update();
        try {
            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.draw(c);
            }
        }finally {
            if(c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps updating my GameView class:

public class GameView extends SurfaceView{

```
private GameThread gameThread;

public GameView(Context context, Activity activity) {
    super(context);
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    init();
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameThread.setRunning(true);
            gameThread.start();

        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
        }
    });
}


public void init() {

}

public void update() {

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

}
}
```

When pressing home my logcat shows this up:

```
02-24 18:24:59.336: E/SurfaceHolder(839): Exception locking surface
02-24 18:24:59.336: E/SurfaceHolder(839): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released.
02-24 18:24:59.336: E/SurfaceHolder(839):   at android.view.Surface.checkNotReleasedLocked(Surface.java:437)
02-24 18:24:59.336: E/SurfaceHolder(839):   at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:245)
02-24 18:24:59.336: E/SurfaceHolder(839):   at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:872)
```

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private GameView gameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this, this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    relativeLayout.addView(gameView);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    gameView.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Please add the main activity code !

Comment: @Jay added the main activity code

Answer (score 2):

The `Surface` underlying the `SurfaceView` gets destroyed between `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` in the app lifecycle.  Send a message to your renderer thread in `onPause()`, and wait for the thread to shut down.

For an example, see the "Hardware scaler exerciser" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  It starts the render thread in the `SurfaceHolder`'s `surfaceCreated()` callback.

**Update:** it felt weird to start the thread in `surfaceCreated()` and stop it in `onPause()`, so after a bit of reshuffling HardwareScalerActivity now stops the thread in `surfaceDestroyed()`.  (The SurfaceView documentation is a bit ambiguous -- it says the Surface is valid "between `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceDestroyed()`" -- but looking at the SurfaceView implementation this appears to be the expected usage.)

**Update 2:** I updated the code some more after finding cases it didn't handle well.  There's now a 60-line megacomment in the sources, which can also been seen in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567641/should-the-renderingthread-of-a-surfaceview-have-the-same-life-cycle-as-the-view/21684399#21684399).

**Update 3:** The mega-comment turned into an [architecture doc appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity).  Grafika's "hardware scaler exerciser" activity demonstrates approach #2, while "texture from camera" demonstrates approach #1.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can make changes to your code like this.

In `GameView`

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
        stop=obj.getBoolean(); //receive status of boolean from main activity

        //stop is boolean set if backPressed in main activity
        if(!stop){ 
        gameThread.setRunning(true);
        gameThread.start();
        }
        else
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
    }
```

In `MainActivity`

```
public Boolean getBoolean(){
return stop;    
} 

public void setBoolean(Boolean bools){
stop=bools;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onBackPressed();

stop=true;
setBoolean(stop);

try{
Thread.sleep(200); // Be safeside and wait for Game thread to finish
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

MainActivity.finish();
}
```

Call `setBoolean` once before backPress else it will give error. Make amendments to code as per your needs.

Hope it helps. Cheers. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trapping on `onBackPressed()` -- there are a number of events that can cause an Activity to pause.  Better to override a lifecycle method (e.g. `onPause()`) and, if you're trying to optimize for rotations, check the value of `isFinishing()`.  If you're going to use a boolean "stop" value communicated between threads, make sure you declare it `volatile`.  And if you need to wait for something to stop, use an explicit wait/notify rather than a sleep, or you're going to get the occasional hard-to-debug failure from devices in the field.